# Magento 1.9.1.1 cron.php High Resource Usage?

Tags: cron, ce-1.9.1.1

I an operating Magento 1.9.1.1 on Arvixe. A few days after upgrading to 1.9.1.1 from 1.9.1.0, I get an email from Arvixe stating:

> Your account is causing high load on the shared server , It is running
>   processes that are consuming high CPU values and for extended periods
>   of time. We had no choice but to disable web accesss for the following
>   script:
>
> ### --  /home/USER/public_html/cron.php
>
> Please have a look at currently running processes for your account and
>   their resource consumption:
>
> lbingman shademountainarmory.com 77.80 0.02 3.8 Top Process %CPU 41.0
>   /usr/bin/php /home/lbingman/public_html/cron.php Top Process %CPU 32.0
>   /usr/bin/php /home/lbingman/public_html/cron.php -mdefault Top Process
>   %CPU 31.0 /usr/bin/php /home/lbingman/public_html/cron.php -malways

Is this something with a newer cron.php file that is hogging resources? If I restore my backup from 1.9.1.0, would that potentially fix this issue?

Basically, because of the script being disabled by the hosting provider, I can get no emails nor send any emails. I'd really like a solution to this as fast as possible.

Comment: did you execute the cronjob via a web call? or did they totally block execution of this script, even via commandline/cron?

Comment: They completely blocked execution of the script.

Comment: Just an update: cron is not being executed by the server. This is odd because nothing has changed. However, I can manually run cron.php by running it in my browser's address bar. But if I do that, I have the same CPU usage issue and it won't stop. I have to rename cron.php to get it to stop. AOE Scheduler shows no pending tasks to be run. I'm at a loss!

Comment: I added "$isShellDisabled = true;" to cron.php and that seems to keep cron under control. I would have thought this issue would have been fixed by Magento, but I guess not.

Answer (score 3):

Normally no, this should not increase much trough this update.

But, its partially normal, that your cron.php needs some CPU, depending which cronjobs you have to run.

With the https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler you can investigate, which of your cronjobs needed longer, this should help to identify and fix the real problem.

Comment: This may not be the answer for 1.9.1.1. I installed AOE Scheduler and it at first appears to work. However, it still shows tasks as pending that should have been executed. Tasks that have been run (or said they have been run) really haven't been run.

Cron.php is still running non-stop causing my CPU usage to be anywhere from 85% to 100%.

Comment: I added "$isShellDisabled = true;" to cron.php and that seems to keep cron under control. I would have thought this issue would have been fixed by Magento, but I guess not.